# Error of iPhone certificate

Tags: iphone, xcode, certificate

I have a big problem.
I have downloed a certificate from apple site.
When I put it into xCode have a warning : "A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain" and can't build the app.
Thanks and sorry for my English XP

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure that AppID tied to provision file coincides with the entered into project settings.